# Core pressure of sphere of fluid in a vacuum

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, gravity, pressure, vacuum

Suppose that we have some known fluid floating in space with no outside gravitational forces. How would we calculate the pressure of the outside fluid on acting on the "core" of the fluid (in other words, the gravitational force the sphere of fluid is exerting on itself)? (This would also assume that the fluid would not evaporate, boil, or change state in general.)

Comment: Derive a formula for pressure at a certain radius by integrating weight at higher radii and dividing by the surface area at that radius. Then take the limit of that as r goes to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the fluid forms a sphere of radius $R$ and is incompressible with constant density $\rho$, we could calculate the pressure it exerts on a smaller sphere of radius $r_1$ by first getting the weight of the fluid above this smaller sphere as follows: 
$$W=\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{r_1}^R\dfrac{G(\rho*\dfrac{4}{3}\pi r^3)}{r^2}\rho r^2\sin(\zeta)dr d\theta d\zeta$$

Where $\dfrac{G(\rho*\dfrac{4}{3}\pi r^3)}{r^2}$ is the strength of the gravitational field at the radius of interest (taking into account the matter inside the sphere of radius of interest). Also, $\rho dV = \rho r^2\sin(\zeta)dr d\theta d\zeta$ in spherical coordinates and constitutes the mass of the portion of mass immediately above the radius of interest.

Solving this integral yields $W=\dfrac{4}{3}\pi ^2 G\rho ^2 (R^4-r_1^4)$ and then the pressure would be the weight divided by the surface area of the sphere of radius $r_1$ $$P=\dfrac{\pi}{3r_1^2} G\rho ^2 (R^4-r_1^4)$$

As you can see, taking the limit when $r_1 \rightarrow 0$, we have $P \rightarrow \infty$ and that is because the area of this sphere becomes infinitely small.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your calculation. Let $V(r)$ be the sphere volume enclosed within radius $r$. Then mass within radius $r$ is $\rho V(r)$ and mass outside radius $r$ is $\rho (V(R)-V(r))$. Then the gravitational force is proportional to $V(r)~(V(R)-V(r))/r^2$. If $A(r)$ is area at radius $r$, then pressure is proportional to $V(r)~(V(R)-V(r))/(r^2 A(r))$. Since $V(r)\sim r^3$ and $A(r)\sim r^2$, for $r\to 0$, pressure goes as $1/r$.

Comment: The whole principal of the integration above was that the weight of fluid at a radius greater than $r$ is not simply a proportionality because when you consider the mass farther and farther from the point of interest, you shouldn't forget that the gravitational field **increases in magnitude**. The proportionality works when the field's magnitude stays approximately the same at the points of interest (like on the surface of the earth and a few kilometers above)